SolidWorks Balloons Not Referencing Top Level Assembly
I am attempting to annotate an exploded view of an assembly that contains subassemblies. In doing so, the balloon references do not match the top-level BOM.
My top-level BOM has 14 items, but the balloon numbers go up to 26, while components of subassemblies each have their own unique item number.
How do I edit the balloons to only reference the top-level BOM? Altering the Balloon Text option does not solve the issue.
See below for mismatch between balloon and top-level BOM.


